# Use an array as parameter when declaring a function, instead of seperate variables

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have this array:

```
$params = array(
'video' => 'xIihy8kkF',
'button' => 'View here',
'title' => 'Video title'
)
```

Now I want to create a function that shows some elements:

```
function show_video($params){
  echo '<div>Video ID:' . $params['video'] . '</div>';
  echo '<div>Button:' . $params['button'] . '</div>';
  echo '<div>Title:' . $params['title'] . '</div>';
}
```

Finally I call the function `show_video()`. But I get an error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function show_video()`

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried changing the function parameters like this:

```
function show_video($video = 'xIihy8kkF', $button = 'View here', $title = 'Video title'){
  // here goes the content
}
```

I just don't want to include all the parameters inside the function name. I want to include them first in a variable array, and then use this array in the function name. Just like I did with `function show_video($params)` , but that is not valid I suppose.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Then it should be `function show_video($params = ['video' => 'xIihy8kkF',
'button' => 'View here',
'title' => 'Video title']){` as the default value for `$params`

Comment: Yes, but as I stated, I prefer to enter all these parameters inside an array instead of adding them seperately inside the function name one by one. Why can't `function show_video($params)` be valid?

Comment: Ok but you wish to call the function as `show_video()` only?

Comment: I will call it like this `show_video($new_params)` where `$new_params` will be an array with different values than `$params`. Simply put, `$params` are the default values of this function and `$new_params` will be the new ones. There will be multiple `$new_params` with different values in each page of the website.

Comment: `function show_video($params){` => Here, `$params` is a local variable. It won't automatically reference your global variable `$params` as the default value.

Comment: @dominotrix I am a bit confused because I don't get any errors when I implement your exact code (your first function definition) and call `show_video($params)`.  I get the following (only with line breaks) in the browser: Video ID:xIihy8kkF
Button:View here
Title:Video title

Comment: @user3425506 That's because I was calling the function like this `show_video()` while you called it like `show_video($params)`. I guess that works for me! Now I can do `show_video($new_params)` with different values.

Comment: @dominotrix You can have a look at splat operator in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Your `show_video` function requires one argument. If you call `show_video()` (i.e. without arguments) you will get an error.

You can solve this in two ways. The first one is to call `show_video($params)` (i.e. provide the required parameter). But it seems that you for some reason don't want to do that.

So, in that case you need to use the `global` keyword to use the `$params` variable inside the function... AND remove the function argument. Like this:

```
$params = array(
    'video' => 'xIihy8kkF',
    'button' => 'View here',
    'title' => 'Video title'
)


function show_video(){
    global $params;    // <-- Add this and remove the argument variable in function
    echo '<div>Video ID:' . $params['video'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div>Button:' . $params['button'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div>Title:' . $params['title'] . '</div>';
}

show_video();
```

However, I would not recommend you to use global variables like this. But sometimes it may be necessary...